# Freemarker: how to specify the value "null" in an expression?

Tags: java, freemarker

I know how to handle nulls (`<#if item?? >...`), but how do you express them as values in an expression?

For example:

```
<#function foo arg1 arg2=null>
    <#if !(arg2??) >
       <#assign arg2 = some_expression_involving_arg1 >
    </#if>
    ...
</#function>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FreeMarker language doesn't know the concept of null. Take a look at this:

http://freemarker.org/docs/app_faq.html#faq_picky_about_missing_vars

However, you could use any value to have the null meaning.

Comment: So there's no way to provide an unused sentinel value as a default value? That sucks. :-(

Comment: I ended up making a NaN value accessible to the freemarker environment (looks like there is no way within freemarker itself) and using that as a sentinel instead. Blech.